# ls invalid option '2'

Tags: command-line, ls

I have the following files (among others) in a directory. I’m running Ubuntu 16.04.

```
 484 May  8 21:50 NA19239.vcf
 484 May  9 08:50 HG01583.vcf
 484 May  9 08:51 HG01595.vcf
   0 May  9 15:11 HG00268-WGS-cordSorted.bam.vcf
   0 May  9 15:11 HG00096-WGS-cordSorted.bam.vcf
   0 May  9 15:11 HG00419-WGS-cordSorted.bam.vcf
```

if I try

```
ls *.vcf
```

I get

```
ls: invalid option -- '2'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

I do not get the error for other file extensions in the directory. I do not get the error for .vcf files when I run the command in other directories. What is causing this error? I have not tried anything except searching for this error. Thanks.

Comment: Probably some badly-named file in your folder which expands into `-2` or something similar. What about the output of this command `ls -- *.vcf`?

Comment: Thats it! had a file that was not supposed to be there with the name -265482.vcf. Can I accept this as an answer. I'm surprised a quick search didn't uncover this immediately.

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Comment: See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1519/85039) post.  Generally, it's suggested to use `./*` instead of wildcard alone. `--` switch can be used, but not all commands have this option, so `./*` is preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have some badly-named file in your folder which expands into `-2...vcf` or something similar. You can run ls in this form: `ls -- *.vcf` to get around it.

Explanation:

BASH performs wildcard expansion before running ls so there is probably something like `ls -2...vcf blabla01.vcf blabla02.vcf` being invoked. By adding two dashes you tell the ls where the parameters end so it treats the `-2...vcf` as a filename argument.

Comment: Is there a way to use the `--` and also output as a single column with `-1`? because it seems that I can't use both together

Comment: You are probably just adding `-1` to the end of the command. That will not work because `-1` is an option. the `--` basically says "no more options after this point". Move the option to the beginning of the command and it should be fine: `ls -1 -- *xml`.